# How to fix "Invalid opcode 153/1/8" in magento?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am using Magento version 1.9. In customer account Wishlist Sharing While i am share my wishlist I am getting following error -

`Fatal error: Invalid opcode 153/1/8. in /home/username/public_html/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php on line 265`

I searched in google and added two line code in the .htaccess file after that i am getting `500 Internal Servr Error`

Code:

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

Please help me.

Comment: check your server logs for details about the 500...

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? (I would guess if it is opcode caching, a restart of PHP-FPM/Apache would highlight this)